# Java Priority Queue Build Heap Process Time Complexity

Tags: java, collections, priority-queue

Build heap has time complexity of O(n). Question is if Java Priority Queue can achieve it?
Let's take a example of Min Heap:
...

```
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,0,1,33));
Queue<Integer> queue=new PriorityQueue<Integer>(list); // Seems O(n) if it uses efficient build heap

while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(queue.poll()); //log(n)
}
```

...

Now as we can see it will do sorting in natural order i.e increasing order.
Java don't have a constructor that takes list as well as comparator.
If I want to create Max Heap, then it will be like this:

...

```
ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,0,1,33));
Queue<Integer> queue=new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
        return arg1.compareTo(arg0);
    }});
for(Integer val:list) {
    queue.offer(val);
}
// nlog(n) in above for loop. Can't use build heap
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(queue.poll());
}
```

...

If I want to use sort custom class using PriorityQueue, then it will never be able to achive build heap O(n). Or can we ?

Answer (score 2):

When I run the following program

```java
System.out.println("Elements    Via constructor      Via offer()");
System.out.println("               Add Then-remove       Add Then-remove");

for(int size: new int[] { 10, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 100_000, 1_000_000 }) {
    int[] comparisons = { 0 };
    class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
        int x;
        Element(int x) { this.x = x; }
        public int compareTo(Element o) {comparisons[0]++;return Integer.compare(x,o.x);}
        @Override public String toString() { return String.valueOf(x); }
    }
    List<Element> samples = IntStream.range(0, size)
        .mapToObj(Element::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    Collections.shuffle(samples, ThreadLocalRandom.current());

    System.out.printf("%8d", samples.size());

    PriorityQueue<Element> q1 = new PriorityQueue<>(samples);
    System.out.printf("%10d", comparisons[0]);
    comparisons[0] = 0;
    while(!q1.isEmpty()) q1.remove();
    System.out.printf("%12d", comparisons[0]);

    comparisons[0] = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Element> q2 = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    for(Element e: samples) q2.offer(e);
    System.out.printf("%10d", comparisons[0]);
    comparisons[0] = 0;
    while(!q2.isEmpty()) q2.remove();
    System.out.printf("%12d", comparisons[0]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

I repeatedly get results in the magnitude of

```
Elements    Via constructor      Via offer()
               Add Then-remove       Add Then-remove
      10        13          27        13          27
     100       169         850       205         850
    1000      1863       14949      2264       14947
   10000     18820      216653     22696      216736
  100000    188046     2831466    228471     2831779
 1000000   1881455    34913307   2281512    34914028
```

showing that adding elements via `offer` does perform more comparisons, but still has an O(n) time complexity. Since retrieving the elements exhibits the O(n log n) complexity, it dwarves the differences in the construction.

Further note that without the shuffle, i.e. with pre-sorted data, there is no difference between the two methods at all. In practice, data will likely be somewhere in-between sorted and entirely random.

So the answer for most practical purposes is that this doesn’t matter.

If you really need to squeeze out the maximum performance in a controlled environment, you could use a hack:

```java
Comparator<Element> comparator = Comparator.naturalOrder();
PriorityQueue<Element> q = new PriorityQueue<>(
    new PriorityQueue<>(comparator) { // not really recommended
        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return samples.toArray();
        }
    });
```

The `PriorityQueue` will take the comparator from the input `PriorityQueue`, but won’t trust the order of the elements in the result of `toArray()` when `getClass() != PriorityQueue.class`, as in this example, and fall back to the same routine it uses when passing an arbitrary collection to the constructor. The net result is the behavior of setting a comparator and initializing with an arbitrary collection input.

Of course, relying on such implementation details is not recommended for any code you plan to give someone else. But unless a future version adds a `PriorityQueue(Collection<? extends E> c, Comparator<? super E> comparator)` constructor, this is the only option to get both into the constructor.

But as shown in the first part of this answer, you might not need this hack anyway, as adding all elements via `offer` also has a reasonable performance.

Comment: I agree that in practice the difference is seldom going to be big deal, but when you teach algorithms and need to explain students that Java standard library did not add a simple constructor therefore there will be lots of extra work for them to use the PriorityQueue.

Oracle should be embarrased that they have not fixed this bug yet as it was registered in 2005. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6356745